# Conditional navigation start destination in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am using `navigation-compose` along with bottom bar in jetpack compose. I want to show different bottom bar for different type of user. For that, I need to set conditional `startDestination` in `NavHost`. How do i do that?

I've tried below but it change `startDestination` but does not reflect in UI.

```
val user by remember { mutableStateOf(viewModel.user) }.collectAsState()
var startDestination = Screens.UserType1.route

LaunchedEffect(user) {
    startDestination = if (loggedInUser?.userType == UserType.Seller) Screens.SellerHome.route else Screens.BuyerHome.route
}
```

While below code throws  `java.util.NoSuchElementException: List contains no element matching the predicate.`

```
when (user?.userType) {
    UserType.Seller -> {
        startDestination = Screens.SellerHome.route
    }

    UserType.Buyer -> {
        startDestination = Screens.BuyerHome.route
    }

    else -> {}
}
```

My NavHost

```
NavHost(
        modifier = modifier,
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = startDestination
) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this

```kotlin
var startDestination = Screens.UserType1.route
```

To this

```kotlin
var startDestination by remember { mutableStateOf(Screens.UserType1.route) }
```

Comment: I played with `remember` and `mutableStateOf()` hundreds of times but still forget this simple thing. Thanks. I love Stack Overflow.